# Pontos de Função são suficientes para consolidar um programa de medição de software?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, requisitos

Pontos de função são o bastante para compor um programa de medição de software ou  existem outras medidas para serem
 usadas em conjunto?

Answer (score 1):

Pontos de função são uma unidade demasiadamente empírica para serem a única forma de medição correta de um programa. Pode-se considerar também a temática da aplicação, e os conhecimentos esperados para a implementação da mesma (frameworks, linguagens, modelamento matemático, conhecimento de temática própria como legislação, circuitos e biologia) versus os conhecimentos dos desenvolvedores alocados, modelados como um cálculo de distância vetorial. Limitações da implementação, como limite de RAM e tempo de operação continua, também podem ser considerados. Lembre-se de que pontos de função são medidas abstratas e pessoais.